# Excel VBA - transfer information from one sheet to a specific cell in a table using a reference number

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet that is being used as an invoice with a reference number and various items that have been selected on the Invoice and would like to copy the selections on that invoice to a different worksheet that is being used as a master database.

Example:
Worksheet 1 (Invoice) has a unique reference in a cell of "Client1"
The client has chosen to buy 2 Apples and 1 Banana and 3 oranges. 
On a separate workbook is a list master database of all clients and their information, name address etc. Column A on this database has the unique reference for each customer i.e Client1, Client2 etc. This spreadsheet also has Apple in Column D, Banana in Column E and Orange in Column F

How would it work that if you click a button once the invoice has been completed and the quantity of items selected for that specific client will populate in the correct fields in the master database based on the unique client reference being used.

i.e - Identify unique reference number on invoice worksheet, find the row with the unique reference number on master database worksheet and put the number 2 in the apples column, 1 in the bananas column and 3 in the oranges column?

Answer (score 0):

Breaking your problem up into a couple of smaller problems:

1. **How to store the value of the customer you are looking up to a variable:**

   You'll need to create a new variable of type "String" to store the value. Then reference the range that holds the customer.

   ```
   Dim strCustomer as String
   strCustomer = Sheet1.Range("A1").value
   ```

   Now you have the customer stored in variable `strCustomer`
2. **How to find that value in a range:**

   Using the `find` method of a `range` you can quickly grab the cell or row or column that the search term is found in your other sheet:

   ```
   Dim rowFoundCustomer as Range
   Set rowFoundCustomer = Sheet2.Range("A:A").Find(strCustomer).EntireRow()
   ```

   Now we have the row (As a range object) that has the unique customer in column A
3. **How to write values in cells that reference that range**

   Now we can just write out to that row, into the appropriate cells, the values for bananas, apples, and whatever you want from your `Sheet1`

   ```
   rowFoundCustomer.Cells(1,4) = Sheet1.Range("B2") 'apples
   rowFoundCustomer.Cells(1,5) = Sheet1.Range("B3") 'bananas
   rowFoundCustomer.Cells(1,6) = Sheet1.Range("B4") 'oranges
   ```

This is all assuming that `Sheet1` has your invoice and `Sheet2` has your master data stuff. Also assuming that Sheet1 `A1` has your customer and `B2, B3, B4` hold your invoice quantities for apples, bananas, and oranges, respectfully.

Putting this together into a subroutine:

```
Sub addToMaster()

    'get the customer from the invoice sheet
    Dim strCustomer As String
    strCustomer = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value

    'find the customer in the master sheet's column A and grab the row
    Dim rowFoundCustomer As Range
    Set rowFoundCustomer = Sheet2.Range("A:A").Find(strCustomer).EntireRow()

    'write back out to the row in columns D, E, and F (4,5 and 6)
    '   the values for our fruits on the invoice
    rowFoundCustomer.Cells(1, 4) = Sheet1.Range("B2") 'apples
    rowFoundCustomer.Cells(1, 5) = Sheet1.Range("B3") 'bananas
    rowFoundCustomer.Cells(1, 6) = Sheet1.Range("B4") 'oranges
End Sub
```

Then you can just plop a button on the sheet and have it point to that sub.